# How to fully use the potential of winter in RPG?

Tags: warhammer

(Warhammer, but diceless)
I have written a short story where my players (a small squad of soldiers) are venturing deeper and deeper into the north chasing their enemies. I want them to hate the winter, hate the climate and hate their sergeant more and more for not letting them start fires, not letting them sleep enough, having shivers, cold food and bleeding lips, I want the players (who are kinda new to RPG) to understand how their characters are feeling and delve into the story.

I'm looking for rules on how to describe winter and what happens with human minds and bodies if you go further and further north. I'd like the climate to sit on their psyche. Does something like that exist anywhere?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So is this a homebrew system, completely free-form or something else?

Comment: @Wibbs it is tagged "Warhammer", I assume the "Warhammer Fantasy" variant.

Comment: @Trish - my query comes from the 'Warhammer but diceless' comment at the start of the question

Answer (score 2):

Are they actually properly equipped for arctic conditions? If not, their sergeant is a fool if he isn't letting them make fires in camp, because it may kill or cripple them. [Frostbite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frostbite) will take fingers, toes, ears and noses.

Most modern people aren't used to being really cold for extended periods. You get more and more tired, something that is easy to role-play, and it gets harder and harder to sleep. You also need a lot more food than in warmer conditions, and the lack of it will make the fatigue even worse.

The easy way to run this is for the cold to do damage to the characters, slowly but inexorably. Some of this can be recovered if they can get warm, and stay that way for a while, but damage they've had for several days could be called frostbite and be lasting, possibly until they can get something that can *regrow* lost bits. Doesn't sound likely in a Warhammer game.

Comment: If they venture far enough northwards, they can find their lost appendages regrowing just fine, and then some.